# delete value input onclick with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, dom

How can I delete any value in input when clicked?
I have two functions `fillField(input)` `function clearField(input)` and which I want to use in all inputs.
My code is:

```js
<script>
// identify form elements:
var search_code = document.getElementById('search_code');
var insert_code = document.getElementById('insert_code');
var result = document.getElementById('result');
var button = document.getElementById('button');

// respond to button click
button.onclick = function validate() {
    // show verification result:
    if(search_code.value == insert_code.value) {
        result.textContent = 'code is ok';
        result.className = "ok";
    } else {
       result.textContent = 'code is not ok';
       result.className = "not-ok";
    }
   // clear input when wrong:
    if (search_code.value !== insert_code.value) {
        insert_code.value = '';
    }
    return false;
};

function fillField(input) {
      if(input.value == "any value")
         input.value="";
};

function clearField(input) {
      if(input.value == "")
         input.value= "any value";
};

insert_code.oninput = function () {
    result.textContent = ''; // clear result;
};
     </script>
```

```html
<form>
        <input type="text" name="search_code" onblur="fillField(this,'insert code');" onfocus="clearField(this,'insert code');" id="search_code" value=""/><br/>
        <input type="" name="insert_code" onblur="fillField(this,'scan code');" onfocus="clearField(this,'scan code');" id="insert_code" placeholder="scand code"value=""/><br/><br/>
        <input type="submit" id="button" name="button" value="validation" />
    </form>
```

Thank you very much!

Comment: `clearField` seems to be doing exactly the opposite of what is supposed to do. Same with `fillField`. `input.value=""` clears the input. It seems you already have everything you need, you just need to wire it up correctly. Please provide a better description of your problem. It's unclear to me what the issue with your code is.

Comment: In my input is any value (text; number; text and number), any. When give click in input I need to delete the values

Comment: So what? For assigning `input.value = ""` it doesn't matter what value the input had before.

Comment: FYI: there's something called [`form.reset()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLFormElement/reset)

Comment: @FelixKling: I edit function `clearField(input) { input.value = "" }` and when give click in input delete value, but value has not saved in input until the next click

Answer (score 0):

I solved this the problem. For those in need, the code is:

```js
<script>
// identify form elements:
var search_code = document.getElementById('search_code');
var insert_code = document.getElementById('insert_code');
var result = document.getElementById('result');
var button = document.getElementById('button');

// respond to button click
button.onclick = function validate() {
    // show verification result:
    if(search_code.value == insert_code.value) {
        result.textContent = 'cod gasit';
        result.className = "ok";
    } else {
       result.textContent = 'codul nu este corect';
       result.className = "not-ok";
    }
   // clear input when wrong:
    if (search_code.value !== insert_code.value) {
        insert_code.value = '';
    }
    return false;
};
//clear text when click on input
function clearField(input) {
         input.value = "";
};

     </script>
```

```html
     <form>
        <input type="text" name="search_code" onfocus="clearField(this, this.placeholder='');" onblur="this.placeholder='introdu codul'" id="search_code" placeholder="introdu codul" autocomplete="off" value=""/><br/>
        <input type="" name="insert_code" onfocus="clearField(this, this.placeholder='');" onblur="this.placeholder='scaneaza codul'" id="insert_code" placeholder="introdu codul" autocomplete="off" value=""/><br/><br/>
        <input type="submit" id="button" name="button" value="verifica COD" />
    </form>
  <div id="result"></div>
```